# Compute $\lim_{x\to-3^-}{\frac{3x-1}{x+1}}$ and $\lim_{x\to-3^+}{\frac{3x-1}{x+3}}$

Tags: limits

Compute each of the following: $$\lim_{x\to-3^-}{\dfrac{3x-1}{x+3}},\lim_{x\to-3^+}{\dfrac{3x-1}{x+3}}$$

I am really not sure how to think about the problem and what the algorithms is. So for $$\lim_{x\to-3^-}{\dfrac{3x-1}{x+3}}$$ the numerator approaches $-10$ and the denominator approaches $0$ but I think with values lower than $0$. And for $$\lim_{x\to-3^+}{\dfrac{3x-1}{x+3}}$$ the numerator also approaches $-10$ and the denominator approaches $0$ but with values greater than $0$.

Comment: $$  \frac{3x+9 - 10}{x+3} = 3 - \frac{10}{x+3}$$   Can you sketch a graph of  $\frac{-10}{x+3} ?  $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in both respects. This should hint that:

- the first limit is $+\infty$ (since the number in bottom gets very small, the number on top approaches an integer, and they both have the same sign)
- the second limit is $-\infty$ (for similar reasons but now they have different signs)

This is also obvious on looking at a graph:

[image]

Rudimentary calculations of the values for $x$ increasingly close to $-3$ likewise confirm this:

[image]

Of course if you want a formal proof you'll need the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition, a bit more complicated to tangle with.

Answer (score 0):

The two limits, from left and from right of $3$, do not exist in $\mathbb{R}$, since they diverge to  $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ (respectively).